static url settings in jinja2
I'm using jinja2 template in Djagon and I want to assign a static url for all my project so that I won't use long relative path in my css and js file. Below is how I set jinja2 template in Django and configured jinja2 environment.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'environment': 'project.utils.jinja2_env.jinja2_environment',
        },
    },
]

def jinja2_environment(**options):
    """
    This is the
    :param options:
    :return:
    """
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': StaticFilesStorage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env

However, when I use the static url in my css or js like:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ static('css/reset.css') }}">

It raised an error like:
  File "***\login.html", line 6, in top-level template code
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ static('css/reset.css') }}">
TypeError: FileSystemStorage.url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

I guess maybe there is some conflict between jinja2 and Django because I can't use Django template suggested like below neither
{% load static %}
{% static 'css/reset.css' %}

I could not figure this out. Someone could help me here? Thanks.
